Terraform Nested loop - Multiple EC2's with multiple EBS Storage blocks
The second for_each loop is not working. I'm trying to write a nested loop that will allow multiple EC2's and each ec2 would be able to have a list of mount names and sizes for ebs volumes
main.tf
# Create resources using for_each

resource "aws_instance" "ec2_instances" {
  for_each = { for inst in var.ec2_instances : inst.name => inst }
  # for_each = var.ec2_instances[].
  
  ami           = each.value.ami
  instance_type = each.value.instance_type
  key_name      = each.value.key_name
  
  
  tags = var.hp_standard_tags

  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = [for volume in var.ec2_instances.ebs_volume : volume.volume_name => volume {
      device_name = volume.volume_name,
      volume_size = volume.volume_size
    }]
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      volume_type           = "gp3"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }

#user_data = file("${path.module}/startup.sh")
}

Variable.tf
variable "ec2_instances" {
  description = "List of EC2 instances"
  type = list(object({
    name               = string
    instance_type      = string
    ami                = string
    key_name           = string
    enable_autoscaling = bool
    ebs_volume = list(object({
      volume_size = string,
    volume_location = string }))
    })
  )
}

variable "standard_tags" {
  description = "Standard set of tags"
  type = object({
    last_review        = string,
    ticket             = string,
    app_name           = string,
    environment        = string,
    hpit_contact_email = string,
    hpit_cost_center   = string,
    hpit_criticality   = string,
    hpit_environment   = string,
    hpit_eprid         = string,
    hpit_mru           = string,
    hpit_role          = string,
    map_id             = string,
    map_prefix         = string
  })
  default = {
    last_review        = "07-12-2024",
    ticket             = "",
    app_name           = "",
    environment        = "dev",
    hpit_contact_email = "",
    hpit_cost_center   = "",
    hpit_criticality   = "",
    hpit_environment   = "",
    hpit_eprid         = "",
    hpit_mru           = "",
    hpit_role          = "",
    map_id             = "",
  map_prefix = "" }
}

variable "date" {
  description = "Run date for the tag"
  type        = string
  default     = "STRING" #"${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD", timeadd(timestamp(), "24h"))}T00:00:00Z"
}

variable "role" {
  description = "dev aws account iam role to be assumed by core tf user"
  type        = string
  default     = ""
}

terraform.tfvars
# List of EC2 instances
ec2_instances = [
  {
    name               = "instance1"
    instance_type      = "t2.micro"
    ami                = "ami-00000000000" # Linux Golden Image Amazon Linux 2023
    key_name           = "your_key_pair_name1"
    enable_autoscaling = false
    ebs_volume = [
      {
        volume_size = "10",
        volume_name = "root"
      },
      {
        volume_size = "60",
        volume_name = "/dev/sg1"
      }
    ]
    #subnet
    #Tags

  },
  {
    name               = "instance2"
    instance_type      = "t2.small"
    ami                = "ami-00000000000" # Windows Golden Image Win 2022
    key_name           = "your_key_pair_name2"
    enable_autoscaling = true
    ebs_volume = [
      {
        volume_size = "10",
        volume_name = "root"
      },
      {
        volume_size = "60",
        volume_name = "/dev/sg1"
      }
    ]
  }
  # Add more instances as needed
]

standard_tags = {
  last_review        = "07-12-2024",
  ticket             = "SR0001",
  app_name           = "TEST",
  environment        = "dev",
  hpit_contact_email = "",
  hpit_cost_center   = "Number",
  hpit_criticality   = "low",
  hpit_environment   = "itg",
  hpit_eprid         = "38001",
  hpit_mru           = "",
  hpit_role          = "",
  map_id             = "",
  map_prefix         = ""
}


To help us answer your question, please do the following; Format your code,  remove any unnecessary comment and code (ex: standard tag block) and fix the code blocks as it seems some text that should be in a code block is not. I personally like to use the ` character to encapsulate code.

"The Second for_each loop is not working." You need to explain what "not working" means here. If the Terraform plan isn't what you expect it to be, then the plan output should be included in your question. Or if there is some sort of error message, then that needs to be included in your question.

Instead of:
  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = [for volume in var.ec2_instances.ebs_volume : volume.volume_name => volume {
      device_name = volume.volume_name,
      volume_size = volume.volume_size
    }]
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.device_name
      volume_type           = "gp3"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }

Try (not tested):
  dynamic "ebs_block_device" {
    for_each = each.value.ebs_volume
    content {
      device_name           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_location
      volume_type           = "gp3"
      volume_size           = ebs_block_device.value.volume_size
      delete_on_termination = true
    }
  }

